# SQL Server's user_id() function equivalent in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am porting a database from SQL Server to Postgresql. I am looking for an equivalent for the `user_id()` function in SQL Server, but from the [postgresql docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-info.html), it appears that there is no equivalent.

`current_user` and its alias `user` are of no use to me, since they return the name (text), and what I want is the id of the user (as returned in SQL Server).

Any help on how to replicate this vital functionality in PG will be much appreciated.

Comment: Postgres has no concept of what user_id means. Why can't you use the text username? Also, it looks like `user_id()` is deprecated anyway http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181466.aspx

Comment: Referential integrity does not require that something is an integer, only that it consistently references some other unique key. The textual username is just as a valid a key to represent "same user" as its numeric ID, and may in some situations be a better choice, e.g. when restoring data to a different cluster where users may have been created in a different order. (And your tone comes across as a little sarcastic there, not sure if you intended that, but if so, please refrain.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in way to get it, but you could certainly make a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION user_id() RETURNS INT AS $$
    SELECT usesysid::int 
    FROM pg_user
    WHERE usename = CURRENT_USER
$$
    LANGUAGE SQL
;
```

Answer (score 3):

The userid is stored in the pg_user table.  Using current_user, you can select the userid. You could write a procedure to wrap this up for you, I'd imagine this is pretty much what the user_id() function is doing behind the scenes, but I'm not aware of an out-of-the-box function that provides it for you already:

```
select usesysid from pg_user where usename = CURRENT_USER;
```

Here is documentation on the pg_user table: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-user.html

Comment: I just came to the same conclusion - I guess I'll wrap a function around it.